# error "The search application on server did not finish loading"

Tags: windows, powershell, sharepoint-2010

> hi I had my **SharePoint** project and when I tried to drag and drop
>   folders to Upload Multi files it doesn't dragged and no files uploaded
>   . when I checked the log file I had this message :
>
> Application Server Administration job failed for service instance
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.
>
> Reason: The search application  on server did not finish loading. View
>   the event logs on the affected server for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2770732

"This is caused by insufficient permissions for the search service account on the SharePoint Server. Verify that no group policies have been set on the local user groups 'WSS_WPG' and 'WSS_ADMIN_WPG'"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when changing the Search DB names and trying to bring the Search service out of suspended state.

Resolution: Ensure that your Search Server Service and your Search Host Controller Service are using the same service account

(Found in "Security > Configure Service Accounts")